# Infimum value of a function in the boundary of a geodesic ball

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth positive function with $f(x_0)=\inf_Mf$ and $\Delta f=1$ in $B_r(x_0)$ and $\Delta f=0$ in $M \setminus  B_{2r}(x_0)$. Can we say that
$$\inf_{\partial B_r(x_0)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}(x)>0 \, ,$$
where $\eta$ is the unit outward normal to $\partial B_r(x_0)$. Here $B_r(x_0)$ is the geodesic ball with center $x_0$ and radius $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot a condition ---
there are no restrictions on $f$ in $B_{2\cdot r}(x_0)\backslash B_r(x_0)$.

So, you may choose any $f$ in $B_r(x_0)$ with $\Delta f=1$ and a minimum at $x_0$.
It is easy to choose $f$ so that your infimum is negative.

Furthermore, choose a harmonic $f$ in $M\setminus B_r(x_0)$ that is larger than $f(x_0)$.
Finally make a smooth transition from $B_r(x_0)$ to $M\setminus B_r(x_0)$.

All this can be done in Euclidean space.